r suppress certain fixed effects in mixed effects model
My goal is to not show the fixed effects model estimates for certain parameters.
Suppose this is my model
# ----preliminaries-------------------------------------------------------
library("lme4")
library("lattice")
library("minqa")
library("nlme")

##-------------------------------------------------------------------------
data("Ovary")

##-------------------------------------------------------------------------
fm1 <- lme(follicles ~ Time + Mare,
           Ovary, random = ~ Time| Mare)
summary(fm1)

This is the result from fitting this model
##-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: Ovary 
       AIC     BIC    logLik
  1719.014 1778.06 -843.5072

Random effects:
 Formula: ~Time | Mare
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
            StdDev   Corr  
(Intercept) 1.906728 (Intr)
Time        3.786740 0     
Residual    3.783546       

Fixed effects:  follicles ~ Time + Mare 
                Value Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept) 10.860030 0.6749929 296 16.089102  0.0000
Time         2.284555 1.2717838 296  1.796339  0.0735
Mare.L       5.623487 2.1982363   0  2.558181     NaN
Mare.Q      -5.736799 2.1967942   0 -2.611441     NaN
Mare.C      -0.264744 2.1958169   0 -0.120567     NaN
Mare^4       0.536030 2.2018435   0  0.243446     NaN
Mare^5       2.288798 2.2023680   0  1.039244     NaN
Mare^6       0.625573 2.2063238   0  0.283536     NaN
Mare^7      -0.431303 2.2007328   0 -0.195982     NaN
Mare^8      -0.224584 2.2045321   0 -0.101874     NaN
Mare^9       2.938148 2.1988367   0  1.336228     NaN
Mare^10      1.104081 2.2042529   0  0.500887     NaN
 Correlation: 
        (Intr) Time   Mare.L Mare.Q Mare.C Mare^4 Mare^5 Mare^6 Mare^7 Mare^8 Mare^9
Time    -0.183                                                                      
Mare.L  -0.002  0.001                                                               
Mare.Q  -0.003  0.001 -0.001                                                        
Mare.C   0.001  0.000 -0.005 -0.003                                                 
Mare^4  -0.003  0.001 -0.001 -0.006 -0.003                                          
Mare^5  -0.002  0.001 -0.005 -0.001 -0.001  0.000                                   
Mare^6  -0.005  0.001 -0.003 -0.001  0.002  0.000  0.000                            
Mare^7  -0.002  0.001 -0.002 -0.001 -0.001  0.002  0.003 -0.001                     
Mare^8   0.001  0.000 -0.001 -0.004  0.000  0.003  0.002 -0.001 -0.002              
Mare^9   0.001  0.000 -0.001 -0.001  0.001  0.001 -0.001  0.001  0.002 -0.003       
Mare^10 -0.005  0.001  0.000  0.005 -0.001 -0.004  0.001  0.004 -0.001 -0.004 -0.002

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-2.73653342 -0.62378080 -0.02311314  0.67691746  2.69728188 

Number of Observations: 308
Number of Groups: 11 

##-------------------------------------------------------------------------
My goal is to exclude fixed effects related to Mare and only show fixed effects estimates for Intercept, Time.
Expecting a model summary like this
##-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
Data: Ovary
AIC     BIC    logLik
1719.014 1778.06 -843.5072
Random effects:
 Formula: ~Time | Mare
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
            StdDev   Corr  
(Intercept) 1.906728 (Intr)
Time        3.786740 0     
Residual    3.783546       

Fixed effects:  follicles ~ Time + Mare 
                Value Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept) 10.860030 0.6749929 296 16.089102  0.0000
Time         2.284555 1.2717838 296  1.796339  0.0735


 Correlation: 
            (Intr) Time   Mare.L Mare.Q Mare.C Mare^4 Mare^5 Mare^6 Mare^7 Mare^8 Mare^9
    Time    -0.183                                                                      
    Mare.L  -0.002  0.001                                                               
    Mare.Q  -0.003  0.001 -0.001                                                        
    Mare.C   0.001  0.000 -0.005 -0.003                                                 
    Mare^4  -0.003  0.001 -0.001 -0.006 -0.003                                          
    Mare^5  -0.002  0.001 -0.005 -0.001 -0.001  0.000                                   
    Mare^6  -0.005  0.001 -0.003 -0.001  0.002  0.000  0.000                            
    Mare^7  -0.002  0.001 -0.002 -0.001 -0.001  0.002  0.003 -0.001                     
    Mare^8   0.001  0.000 -0.001 -0.004  0.000  0.003  0.002 -0.001 -0.002              
    Mare^9   0.001  0.000 -0.001 -0.001  0.001  0.001 -0.001  0.001  0.002 -0.003       
    Mare^10 -0.005  0.001  0.000  0.005 -0.001 -0.004  0.001  0.004 -0.001 -0.004 -0.002
    
    Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
            Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
    -2.73653342 -0.62378080 -0.02311314  0.67691746  2.69728188 
    
    Number of Observations: 308
    Number of Groups: 11 

I am not sure how to apply functions only to exclude model estimates from one parameter (mare). Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks.

If you don't mind me asking: why?

try coef(summary(model))[1:2, ].

The answer to your previous question also works here.

@user2554330, no it does not. if I use the previous solutions, the random effects part of the summary disappears. I like to retain everything from the model summary except the estimates for certain factors.

@ZéLoff, good question. In causal inference, the scientists are mostly interested in seeing results only related to exposures. Rest are confounders they are not interested in exploring confounders due to Table2 fallacy.

@AhirBhairavOrai:  you should edit your question to show your attempt to use the previous solution.  Then someone can explain how to fix it.

@Ahir Bhairav Orai if it's not relevant to you, you can always ignore them.  But you should take a look at them anyway. E.g., in your example, there is clearly something odd with the fit, but you might not notice it if the summary is truncated. If its for reporting purposes, you can use the broom package to get the fitting summary as a data.frame, and then filter as you please. But plainly ignoring terms sounds like a bad idea, IMHO.
